# OpenCV Video Editing?

Tags: c++, image, video, opencv, gaussian

I am using OpenCV and trying to apply a Gaussian Blur to an incoming video stream. I basically use cvQueryFrame to remove a frame, blur it and display the frame onto the screen. The thing is though, my video gets stuck on the first frame after I apply the blur....anyone know why? its basically showing one frame instead of a video. The second I remove the blur it starts outputting video again.

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include "cvaux.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

//declare initial data
IplImage *grabCapture= 0; //used for inital video frame capture
IplImage *process =0; //used for processing
IplImage *output=0; //displays final output

CvCapture* vidStream= cvCaptureFromCAM(0);

cvNamedWindow ("Output", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

int createimage=1;

while (1)
{

grabCapture= cvQueryFrame (vidStream);

if (createimage==1)
    {
        process= cvCreateImage (cvGetSize(grabCapture), IPL_DEPTH_16U, 3);

        createimage=0;

    }

*process=*grabCapture;
cvSmooth (process,process,CV_GAUSSIAN,7,7); //line that makes it display frame instead of video


cvShowImage("Output",process);

}


//clean up data
cvReleaseImage (&grabCapture);
cvReleaseImage (&process);
cvReleaseImage (&output);
cvReleaseCapture (&vidStream);


return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a call to `cvWaitKey`. This is the only way to tell OpenCV to process events and thus prevent the GUI from freezing.

Try adding this line:

```
cvWaitKey(10);
```

after `cvShowImage("Output",process);`.

Edit: here is the documentation for [cvWaitKey](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/user_interface.html#waitkey)

Comment: Thanks, but isn't cvwaitkey() just for user input?
Why is it needed when just processing images?
Thank You :)

Comment: That's what the name would suggest, but it is also used for event processing. Take a look at the note in the documentation I linked to. Not sure why it was done this way, though. Keep in mind highgui isn't intended to be a full-fledged windowing system anyway. By the way, did you solve the problem?

Comment: Allright Thank You for your help :) And Yes it did solve the problem :) Just one more question My video lags a LOT is there anyway to make the video real time? As in increase the speed of the Gaussian Blur? Thanks

Comment: @Farhad. If the answer solved your problem, you should accept it. If you have additional questions, don't put them in a comment, make a new question. Please [read about accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).